Homotopy and fundamental group in practice (reference request)
I'm studying topology and a question has come to my mind.
I'm currently dealing with homotopy (of continuous functions, of paths and of topological spaces), with the fundamental group of a pointed topological space (explored mainly via the SVK theorem, without covering theory), and the related notions of contractible spaces, simply connected spaces, retracts and so on, constituting the poisonous tail of my first course in general and algebraic topology.
Although I have studied the theory and proofs in detail, I am quite disappointed when turning to the exercises: most of them seem just 'hand-shaking' graphical or algebraic tricks which I cannot neither justify nor replicate by myself, ability which is indeed demanded in exams, sometimes even in detail. I therefore ask for a reference containing concrete examples worked out in sufficient detail and possibly not only showing the way but also the underlying ideas.

Could you give (an) example(s) of these exercises that rely on hand-waving graphical or algebraic tricks?

@BenSteffan I'll just mention the last one (not completely since it would require a graph): in R^2, consider a full hexagon with a square hole in it; identify pairwise the opposite sides of the square (with same verses), then identify two adjacent sides of the hexagon with a non-adjacent side, and at last two other opposite sides of the hexagon. The aim is to calculate the fundamental group of the obtained space. It turns that the space can be though as a limited pseudo-cylinder in R^3 having the square on one side and the hexagon on the other which ultimately turn to be just loops.

@BenSteffan My inability to better picture the situation may be related to my narrow comprehension of the relevant details, by which my reference request.

Let me suggest that your post, as currently stated, is going to be rather difficult to answer in a manner satisfactory to you. But on the other hand a concrete mathematical question about a specific problem, for example a question about the hexagon-with-square-hole example in your comment, would work out much better.

There is indeed a gap of intuition between the formal mathematics and the graphical/algebraic tricks, you are right about that. But I don't think anything is going to aid you in spanning that gap better than working through specific problems and asking questions about them.

@LeeMosher Thank you for your suggestion. Do you mean that there is no book brave enough to explore that gap? It's certainly not the first time I pop up into exercises seeming "on another planet" with respect to theory, but in most cases it turns out just the theory being too formal, or not enough thorough or motivated with examples. In most of the cases, although not immediately, I succeeded in finding a better reference.

Well, I could point you to particular books that I like and teach from (Munkres, Hatcher), but I cannot tell you whether those books explore the gap as you perceive it. That's part of the difficulty with your question as currently posted, it's rather subjective. The gist of my suggestion is that you can be much more objective with actual mathematical questions about actual mathematical problems.

Such questions work much better on this site.

@LeeMosher I get this point. It may turn out to be the only way. Let's see.
